# Why is there no laser_scan_matcher in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, laser-scan-matcher

I was just wondering why there has not been an official port of the laser_scan_matcher to ROS2 with binaries. It seems like such a useful package to improve bad odometry.

Is this functionality not needed anymore?

Answer (score 2):

I find a GitHub repository https://github.com/AlexKaravaev/ros2_laser_scan_matcher which maybe meet you need(though it's not official)